# Xamarin.Forms can't display image in list

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView with several items in it.  I am running the app as a UWP app on my local machine, but for some reason, displaying an image via a url doesn't work?

The tag I'm using is

`<Image Source="https://en.bitcoin.it/w/images/en/2/29/BC_Logo_.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" />`

I have tried using several different images from different domains as I thought it could be an authorisation issue? But no images that I've tried seem to be working.

As I define the space for the image, there is a gap in the list where it should be.

For reference, here is the whole list code:

```
<ContentPage Title="Coins">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="coins" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout Spacing="5" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,10,10,10">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Path=Rank}" FontSize="10" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Image Source="https://en.bitcoin.it/w/images/en/2/29/BC_Logo_.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Path=Name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="19" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Path=PercentChange24h, StringFormat='{0}%'}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="{Binding PercentTextColour}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Path=LivePrice, StringFormat='${0}'}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was down to UWP not being able to display images, this works on Android and iOS.